# how do i ignore/fix Raven scans vulnerabilities for npm library dependencies

Tags: angularjs, security, npm, package.json

We have a web application on AngularJS 1.x which is creating issues with dependencies -> dependent library to raven scan vulnerabilities.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.6.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.6.6",
    "angular-aria": "1.6.9",
    "angular-material": "1.1.9",
    "angular-messages": "1.6.9",
    "angular-route": "1.6.9",
    "angular-touch": "1.6.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.2",
    "angular-smart-table": "2.1.8",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-ui-grid": "4.8.3",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.12.10",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "requirejs": "2.3.6",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "grunt-cli": "1.3.2",
    "grunt": "1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "2.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-processhtml": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-front-end-modules": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "3.0.0",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "d3": "3.5.17",
    "nvd3": "1.8.1",
    "angular-file-saver": "1.1.3",
    "smart-area": "2.0.0",
    "csv-js": "1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "0.1.36",
    "file-saver": "1.3.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "angular-file-upload": "2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Package-lock.json

```
...

"htmlprocessor": {
      "version": "0.2.6",
      "resolved": "https://fakepath",
      "integrity": "sha1",
      "requires": {
        "lodash": "~2.4.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": {
          **"version": "2.4.2",**
          "resolved": "https://fakepath",
          "integrity": "sha1"
        }
      }
    },
...
```

For example above - lodash needs to be updated to 4.17.20 of min to fix the vulnerability.

**Do i add lodash to be a devDependency or update the package-lock.json manually ?**

*Note- package-lock.json is not pushed as part of source control but i am studying online that it should be*

Answer (score 0):

We're working off security vulnerabilities in our apps as well and have had a similar problem. There is no good answer:

- Sure, you can edit your package-lock.json file by hand but that's just cheating around the issue. It won't somehow get rid of the vulnerability that lodash is bringing in because NPM will keep pulling down that version. You would be better off asking for a waiver for this security finding than trying to hide it.
- Why is it pulling down that version? One of your devDependencies has a dependency on htmlprocessor. That processor lib [specifically calls out the use of that version of lodash](https://github.com/dciccale/node-htmlprocessor/blob/master/package.json#L42). You could submit a merge request to that library to get it updated to a newer version of lodash but it doesn't look like it's maintained anymore.
- Adding a newer version of lodash as a devDependency will just mean you now depend on two versions of lodash. It won't fix anything.

This is both the blessing and curse of using NPM. Easy access to tons of libraries... but there are many no-longer-maintained libraries that get pulled in that are chock full of security issues.